# How do you upload a file from the pc to your Trello boards?

Tags: trello, trello-boards

How do you upload a file from the pc to your Trello boards?

We have followed instructions but nothing happened and we have no link on the board to do this - is it because I do not use Google Chrome?

Answer (score 2):

1. Click on a card
2. Click the <kbd>Attach a File...</kbd> button on the right side of the dialog that opens

[image: Attach File...]